# What is the purpose of _abck and bm_sz?

Tags: cookies, httpcookie

I see some website uses _abck, bm_sz cookies. But if I don't send them back to the server. It seems to work. What are _abck and bm_sz cookies for?

Comment: "_abck" appears to be related to an anti-bot library: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/182895/anti-bot-javascript-library-identification.  The purpose of the other is unknown, but possibly the same.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the same and found that they both belong to Akamai Bot Manager.

[IKEA](https://www.ikea.com/es/en/files/pdf/63/a3/63a338ba/cookie_policy.pdf)'s and [Choice Hotels](https://www.choicehotels.it/en/it-cookie-policy)' cookie policies helped solidify the research I did on the subject.