# Python Requests login: i have error 403 but the request looks correct

Tags: python, session, web-scraping, python-requests, cors

I am trying to login into www.zalando.it using the requests library, but every time I try to post my data I am getting a 403 error. I saw in the network tab from Zalando and the login call and is the same.
These are just dummy data, you can test creating a test account.

Here is the code for the login function:

```
import requests
import pickle
import json

session = requests.session()
headers1 = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36'}
r = session.get('https://www.zalando.it/', headers = headers1)
cookies = r.cookies

url = 'https://www.zalando.it/api/reef/login'   
payload = {'username': "email@email.it", 'password': "password", 'wnaMode': "shop"}
headers = {
    'x-xsrf-token': cookies['frsx'],
    #'_abck': str(cookies['_abck']),
    'usercentrics_enabled' : 'true',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36",
    'origin':'https://www.zalando.it',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'no-cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'dpr': '1.3125',
    'referer': 'https://www.zalando.it/uomo-home/',
    'viewport-width': '1464'
    }
x = session.post(url, data = json.dumps(payload), headers = headers, cookies = cookies)
print(x) #error 403
print(x.text) #page that show 403
```

Comment: i'm not using selenium, with selenium i can login without problems. Already tried

Comment: Did you try adding this portion `session.headers['Zalando-Client-Id'] = r.cookies['Zalando-Client-Id']` to see what you get?

Comment: I just tried but the same error 403. I added this in the header bracket `'Zalando-Client-Id': cookies['Zalando-Client-Id']`

Comment: I tried with your solution, even adding all the headers but nothing. Error 403

Comment: Maybe try doing a GET request to the homepage before doing the POST request. The first request might set some cookies.

Comment: Hi, do you solved this problem? I'm doing the same script

Answer (score 3):

For the initial request it needs to look like an actual browser request, after that the headers need to be modified to look like an [xhr (Ajax) request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). Also, there's some response headers that need to be added to future requests to the server, along with cookies such as the client-id and an [xsrf token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

Here's some example code that is currently working:

```
import requests

# first load the home page
home_page_link = "https://www.zalando.it/"
login_api_schema = "https://www.zalando.it/api/reef/login/schema"
login_api_post = "https://www.zalando.it/api/reef/login"

headers = {
    'Host': 'www.zalando.it',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection' : 'close',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'
}


if __name__ == '__main__':

    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers.update(headers)

        r = s.get(home_page_link)

        # fetch these cookies: frsx, Zalando-Client-Id
        cookie_dict = s.cookies.get_dict()
        # update the headers
        # remove this header for the xhr requests
        del s.headers['Upgrade-Insecure-Requests']
        # these 2 are taken from some response cookies
        s.headers['x-xsrf-token'] = cookie_dict['frsx']
        s.headers['x-zalando-client-id'] = cookie_dict['Zalando-Client-Id']
        # i didn't pay attention to where these came from
        # just saw them and manually added them
        s.headers['x-zalando-render-page-uri'] = '/'
        s.headers['x-zalando-request-uri'] = '/'
        # this is sent as a response header and is needed to 
        # track future requests/responses
        s.headers['x-flow-id'] = r.headers['X-Flow-Id']
        # only accept json data from xhr requests
        s.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'

        # when clicking the login button this request is sent 
        # i didn't test without this request
        r = s.get(login_api_schema)

        # add an origin header
        s.headers['Origin'] = 'https://www.zalando.it'
        # finally log in, this should return a 201 response with a cookie
        login_data = {"username":"email@email.it","password":"password","wnaMode":"modal"}
        r = s.post(login_api_post, json=login_data)
        print(r.status_code)
        print(r.headers)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution @bmcculley. It seems to be working.

Comment: Your solution was working yesterday but it is not working now. Is there any reason for this behavior? Thanks in advance for the clarity @bmcculley.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems to me that this website is protected by Akamai (looks like [Akamai Bot Manager](https://developer.akamai.com/akamai-bot-manager)).

See that `Server: AkamaiGHost` in the response headers of `/api/reef/login` when you get a 403 response?
Also, have a look at the requests sent during a legitimate browser session: there are many requests sent to `/static/{some unique ID}`, with some `sensor_data`, including your user-agent, and some other "gibberish".

The above description seems to fit this one:

> The BMP SDK collects behavioral data while the user is interacting with the application. This behavioral data, also known as sensor data, includes the device characteristics, device orientation, accelerometer data, touch events, etc. <sup>Reference: [BMP SDK](https://developer.akamai.com/tools/sdk/bot-manager)</sup>

Also, [this answer confirms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60043117/1079047) that some of the cookies set by this website in fact belong to Akamai Bot Manager.

Well, I'm not sure if there's an easy way of bypassing it. After all, that's a product developed exactly for this purpose - block web-scraping bots like yours.